# Stoichiometry Assignment

Tags: stoichiometry

$\ce{2Ca3(PO4)2 +6SiO2 +10C->6CaSiO3 +P4 +10CO}$

What is the maximum amount of P4 that can be produced from 1.0 kg of phosphorite if the phosphorite sample is 75% $\ce{2Ca3(PO4)2}$ by mass

---

I am confused. How do I find a maximum amount of a reaction

Answer (score 1):

Phosphorite is a mineral containing calcium phosphate. This particular 1kg sample has 75% percent of it by weight i.e. 750 grams. All others reagents are assumed to be in excess as you have to find the maximum p4 obtained which would be at a point where all of our mineral is used.